# Fastest way for return rows count with where clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, count, query-optimization

I have big log4net database table with this structure.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [Application] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Server] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [VARCHAR](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [TEXT] NULL,
    [UserName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [VARCHAR](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

But this table has cca 250 000 000 rows. I need return count for table. Standard way is (generated by entity framework )

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  ((([Extent1].[Level] = 'DEBUG')
                 AND ('DEBUG'  IS NOT NULL))
                 OR (([Extent1].[Level] = 'INFO')
                     AND ('INFO'  IS NOT NULL))
                 OR (([Extent1].[Level] = 'WARN')
                     AND ('WARN'  IS NOT NULL)))
                     OR (([Extent1].[Logger] = 'PlusService')
                         AND ('PlusService' IS NOT NULL))) AS [GroupBy1]
```

but is very slow, average 5 minutes with litle where. I need using where clausule. Is there possible how i can using system count methods like this ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, rows)
FROM sysindexes
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Log')
AND indid < 2
```

or this

```
SELECT CAST(p.rows AS float)
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS idx ON idx.object_id = tbl.object_id and idx.index_id < 2
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id=CAST(tbl.object_id AS int)
AND p.index_id=idx.index_id
WHERE ((tbl.name=N'Log'
AND SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)='dbo'))
```

or this

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Log')   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

These three options I mentioned above are very fast. But I think it does not support using where clause. Is there any way that I can use methods like this?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `Level`/`Logger` columns?

Comment: Yes, but I need very fast insert, because I have 400,000 inserts per hour at peak.

Comment: First of all there is something quite unclear to me in 
...
                 OR (([Extent1].[Level] = 'INFO')
                     AND ('INFO'  IS NOT NULL))
...
and all the others inside the where clause: why are you checking if a valued string is not null? May be you meant to compare Extent1.Level.
Going back to main topic, there is no way to use where for those queries, but you could create additional table(s) and refer to them using indexes, for example for the Level values. Alternatively, if there are just few Logger values, you could create dedicated table for each logger